# The way to ensure some code always run outside any AR transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say, I have some public method in the Active Record model:

```
def run_async
  # some code I do not want to exec while transaction opened
end
```

And I'm not ensure this method will not be called from transaction. So is any way to wrap it and call right after transaction end? Something like

```
def run_async
  after_transaction do
    # some code I do not want to exec while transaction opened
  end
end
```

Comment: you may want to use http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit

Comment: @ArupRakshit in fact I use it now, but it's good only for private methods, for public methods there are no guaranties it is not run from another class' transaction.

Comment: I don't get you. this model callbacks trigger when that specific model is getting saved/updated/destroyed. What do you mean by `public` and `private` method ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I mean exactly what public and private modifiers mean in Ruby - public methods could be called on class instance from any piece of code and you (as class maintainer) could not control it.

Comment: callback methods works, which are tagged with `private`.. Sorry, I still didn't get you.. :)